# Does ALB ingress controller monitor ALB configuration and reconcile with the desired ingress state stored in etcd?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-elb, ingress-controller

I know controllers like replicaset will reconcile the current running number of replicas with the desired number, for example, if the desire replica is 3, for some reason, 1 replica is down, the controller learns this information and tries to bring up a new one so that the total replica equals 3.

But how about the configuration in an external resource that is managed by for example ALB Ingress controller. The ALB is first created and then configured with the ingress resource, but later on, if I manually change something in the ALB, for example, delete a certificate, delete a rule/listener, etc., does the ingress controller monitor this, and reconcile the ALB configuration with the status in Kubernetes, i.e., the desired state?

I asked this question because it doesn't seem to work this... But I will like to confirm and understand why this is not the default behaviour.